# Teamspeak-Query get's blocked by User after joining

Tags: java, teamspeak

i program a query thats writes each user a message after join. The query is already blocked before the users can join and receive the message. The bot runs over the holywaffle-teamspeak-api.

```
public class Main {

public static TS3Config config = new TS3Config();
public static TS3Query query = new TS3Query(config);
public static TS3Api api = new TS3Api(query);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // connection settings
    config.setHost("XX");
    query.connect();

    // api settings
    api.login(Config.getInstance().query_name, "XX");
    config.setQueryPort(Config.getInstance().query_port);
    config.setFloodRate(FloodRate.UNLIMITED);
    config.setDebugToFile(true);
    api.selectVirtualServerById(1);
    api.setNickname(Config.getInstance().bot_nickname);
    config.setDebugLevel(Level.ALL);

    // loading all methods
    TS3Events.load();
    Config.main(args);
    Debugg.debugg();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform asynchronous actions such as listening for events (client connections), you need to use the asynchronous library

From the README:

> Features
>
> - Contains almost all server query functionality! (see [TeamSpeak 3 Server Query
>     Manual](http://media.teamspeak.com/ts3_literature/TeamSpeak%203%20Server%20Query%20Manual.pdf))
> - Built-in keep alive method
> - Threaded event-based system
> - **Both synchronous**
>     **and**
>     **asynchronous**
>     **implementations available**
> - Can be set up to reconnect and automatically resume execution after a connection problem
> - Utilizes [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) for logging abstraction and integrates with your logging configuration

The the asynchronous class is `TS3ApiAsync`:

https://github.com/TheHolyWaffle/TeamSpeak-3-Java-API/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/theholywaffle/teamspeak3/TS3ApiAsync.java

**[EDIT]** Here is an example using the asynchronous library in case you are unfamiliar:

https://github.com/TheHolyWaffle/TeamSpeak-3-Java-API/blob/master/example/TrollExample.java